# Installing competing library versions

Tags: centos, rhel, yum, rpm

On a CentOS 7 system, I have software installed that links to the `libpqxx` package from EPEL, which is version 4. I am trying to install software which links to the `libpqxx` package from the PostgreSQL repository, which is version 5, but despite the two packages having completely different sets of files, I am unable to get yum to install the two packages side by side:

```
/usr/lib64/libpqxx-4.0.so
/usr/share/doc/libpqxx-4.0.1
/usr/share/doc/libpqxx-4.0.1/AUTHORS
/usr/share/doc/libpqxx-4.0.1/COPYING
/usr/share/doc/libpqxx-4.0.1/ChangeLog
/usr/share/doc/libpqxx-4.0.1/NEWS
/usr/share/doc/libpqxx-4.0.1/README
/usr/share/doc/libpqxx-4.0.1/VERSION
$ rpm -qlp libpqxx-5.0.1-2.rhel7.1.x86_64.rpm 
/usr/lib64/libpqxx-5.0.so
/usr/share/doc/libpqxx-5.0.1
/usr/share/doc/libpqxx-5.0.1/ChangeLog
/usr/share/doc/libpqxx-5.0.1/README.md
```

I get errors:

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: 1:libpqxx-devel-4.0.1-1.el7.x86_64 (@epel)
           Requires: libpqxx(x86-64) = 1:4.0.1-1.el7
           Removing: 1:libpqxx-4.0.1-1.el7.x86_64 (@epel)
               libpqxx(x86-64) = 1:4.0.1-1.el7
           Updated By: 1:libpqxx-5.0.1-2.rhel7.1.x86_64 (/libpqxx-5.0.1-2.rhel7.1.x86_64)
               libpqxx(x86-64) = 1:5.0.1-2.rhel7.1
Error: Package: NNNN (@/c6b4a439fe91e032)
           Requires: libpqxx-4.0.so()(64bit)
           Removing: 1:libpqxx-4.0.1-1.el7.x86_64 (@epel)
               libpqxx-4.0.so()(64bit)
           Updated By: 1:libpqxx-5.0.1-2.rhel7.1.x86_64 (/libpqxx-5.0.1-2.rhel7.1.x86_64)
              ~libpqxx-5.0.so()(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Is there a way to install both, or do I need to repack them manually to have the RPMs use different names?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot install two different versions of the same package with `rpm`. So I'm affraid you would need to do repackaging in this case.

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34683225/rpm-spec-how-to-allow-multiple-versions) they talk about **installOnlyPackages**, but I don't think that is what you want.